# Solution to declare object. Says that it expects int[][]

Tags: java, object

I am asked to print the total, average, highestInRow, lowestInRow, rowTotal,colTotal of a two dimensional array. I have some errors that show.

They want the output to be this way.

> Processing iarray.
>
> Total : 45
>
> Average : 5.0
>
> Total of row 0 : 12
>
> Total of row 1 : 14
>
> Total of row 2 : 19
>
> Total of col 0 : 14
>
> Total of col 1 : 10
>
> Total of col 2 : 21
>
> Highest in row 0 : 9
>
> Highest in row 1 : 7
>
> Highest in row 2 : 8
>
> Lowest in row 0 : 1
>
> Lowest in row 1 : 3
>
> Lowest in row 2 : 5

Here is my code

```
public class Int2DArray
{
    private int[][] array = { { 2,1,9},{7,3,4},{5,6,8} };



    public Int2DArray(int[][] newArray )
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
        {
            array[i][i] = newArray[i][i];
        }
    }

    public int getTotal( int total)
    {
        total = 0 ;

        for( int row = 0 ; row < array.length ; row++ )
        {

            for ( int col = 0 ; col < array[row].length ; col ++ )
                total+= array[row][col];
        }
        return total;
    }

    public double getAverage ( double average )
    {
        int total = 0 ;
        average = getTotal(total)/array.length;
        return average;
    }

    public int getRowTotal ( int rowTotal )
    {
        for ( int row = 0 ; row < array.length ; row ++ )
        {
            for ( int col = 0 ; col < array[row].length ; col ++ )
                rowTotal += array[row][col];
        }
        return rowTotal;
    }

    public int getColumnTotal ( int colTotal )
    {
        for ( int col = 0 ; col < array[0].length ; col ++ )
        {
            for ( int row = 0 ; row < array.length ; row ++ )
                colTotal+= array[row][col];
        }
        return colTotal;
    }

    public void getHighestInRow ()
    {
        int max = 0 ; 
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        {
            max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            for ( int j = 0; j < array [ i ].length; j++ )
                if ( array [ i ] [ j ] > max )
                    max = array [ i ] [ j ];
            System.out.println( "Maximum of row " + i + " = " + max );
        }
    }

    public void getLowestInRow ()
    {
        int min = 0 ;
        for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ )
        {
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for ( int j = 0; j < array [ i ].length; j++ )
                if ( array [ i ] [ j ] < min )
                    min = array [ i ] [ j ];
            System.out.println( "Minimum of row " + i + " = " + min );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]Args)
    {
        int total = 0 ; 
        double average = 0 ;
        int rowTotal = 0 ;
        int colTotal = 0 ;

        Int2DArray object1 = new Int2DArray () ;

        System.out.println(" The Total of the Array is : " + object1.getTotal(total));
        System.out.println(" The Average of the Array is : " + object1.getAverage(average));
        System.out.println(" The Row Total of the Array is : " + object1.getRowTotal(rowTotal));
        System.out.println(" The Column Total of the Array is : " + object1.getColumnTotal(colTotal));
        System.out.println(" The Highest variable in a row of the Array is : " + object1.getHighestInRow());
        System.out.println(" The Lowest variable in a row of the Array is : " + object1.getLowestInRow());

    }
}
```

Comment: "I have some errors that show." So tell us what they are, and do it in the text, rather than in code... and then format your code properly. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constructor makes no sense:

```
public Int2DArray(int[][] newArray )
{
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ )
    {
        array[i][i] = newArray[i][i];
    }
}
```

It's initializing your array[][] multiple times, which makes no sense in itself, but you also already initialized the array with this code:

```
private int[][] array = { { 2,1,9},{7,3,4},{5,6,8} };
```

So changing it to

```
public Int2DArray()
{
}
```

Would be a big step forward to start with.

Side note: this would be equivalent to simply deleting the constructor, since the empty constructor is implicit in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since your constructor is declared to receive a parameter `int[][]`, when you initialize the `Int2DArray` object, you will have to pass an array. If you don't want to do this, you could define a constructor with no parameters:

```
public Int2DArray() { }
```

Another problem is in these lines:

```
System.out.println(" The Highest variable in a row of the Array is : " + object1.getHighestInRow());
System.out.println(" The Lowest variable in a row of the Array is : " + object1.getLowestInRow());
```

Since the methods `getHighestInRow()` and `getLowestInRow()` don't return anything (`void`) and print the results by themselves, you have to call them like:

```
System.out.println(" The Highest variable in a row of the Array is : ");
object1.getHighestInRow();

System.out.println(" The Lowest variable in a row of the Array is : ");
object1.getLowestInRow();
```